# How do I determine the C compiler in a github action?

Tags: c, github, github-actions

Short version of the question: Is there any easy way of determining the version of the C compiler and incorporating that version into the key for a cache name?

Long version: I have a series of tests.  I need to compile about 2000 files that almost never change in order to create a library. To speed up the tests, these 2000 files are compiled, and the resulting archive is saved in a github cache.  Later runs can see that these 2000 files haven't changed, and can reuse the same archive.

But it now appears that there are two different versions of the C compiler, 14.36.32532 and 14.36.32215 on the windows machines. If the cache is built with one compiler, it will fail to link with binaries built with the other compiler.  If I could find out the C compiler, I could create a separate cache for each compiler version.  That would also help future-proof me against further changes to the compiler.

---

Update 3/17 for longish response to Azeem. Another commenter also believed this was the XY Problem.  I think I'm coming up with the only obvious explanation given by the logs, but maybe I'm wrong.

3 days ago, I had four Windows machines running simultaneously.  All were identical except for the version of Python they were running.  All compiled C code using the exact same command `python setup.exe build_ext --inplace`.  Three finished just fine, one failed.

When I looked at the logs, the failing image said it was using cl.exe 14.36.32532.  The passing images were all using 14.36.32215.  The failing image specifically mentioned that it could not link against pre-built libraries compiled with a different version of the C compiler.

I looked at other logs and saw that some had 14.36.32215, while others had 14.36.32532.  It was independent of the Python version used to start the compiler.

And I looked at actions run a month ago, and I'm seeing 14.34.31933.  So it seems the compiler is constantly being updated.  There just happened to be a snag where two were supposed to be compatible and weren't???

Comment: @user3386109.  I'm getting an error from the linker.  And when I delete the cache and thereby force everything to be compiled at once, it always works.   "fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\mylib_1.lib' was created by a different version of the compiler than other objects like 'build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\swig\stuff_wrap.obj'; rebuild all objects and libraries with the same compiler.

Comment: @user3386109.  And I've gone back through several days of tests.  The only difference between working tests and failing tests is the version of the release that appears in the link command.

Comment: Well, my question wasn't: "Why am I getting this error?" but "How do I figure out what compiler version I'm running?"  I didn't know enough to even consider that the versions ought to be compatible.   And for the sake of sanity and not giving a future developer a headache, I'm happy with a new version of the compiler requiring a new cache, even if they're supposed to be compatible.

Comment: Isn't the same Windows runner running the subsequent workflows? On GHA-hosted preinstalled Windows runners, the VC++ is the same i.e. 14.36.32532. See https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md#microsoft-visual-c and https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#microsoft-visual-c. Where is **14.36.32215** coming from? Please include some more context about your GHA workflow and its runner i.e. GHA-hosted or self-hosted. If it's self-hosted, you can simply install the same version.

Comment: @Azeem.  I'm caching the libraries.  So on Monday, a Windows runner would build the library, finish the rest of the tests, and then save the libraries.  On Tuesday, a different Windows runner would see that it could reuse the libraries built the day before.  I now know I can only reuse the cache if they were built with the same compiler.

Comment: But, why would there be different compilers if your workflows are using the same runner image? Are you using self-hosted Windows runners with different compiler versions?

Comment: @Azeem.  Excellent question.  I'm just using `runs-on: windows-latest` and sometimes I'm getting one compiler and sometimes I'm getting a different one.  I wished I had a better explanation.  All I can do is report what I'm seeing in the logs.

Comment: A runner image cannot just change its installed tools between workflow runs. Lately, there has not been any changelog entry for moving `windows-latest` to some other version so that's highly unlikely. Please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question. It's starting to feel like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) now. Your workflow would definitely be helpful to understand your issue better.

Comment: @Azeem.  Added longish comment to my original post.

Comment: Thanks! But, there are no logs or a reproducible workflow in your question. It'll only be guesswork without those. As of now, is that workflow failing with the same error?

Comment: **I had four Windows machines running simultaneously.** What do mean by this? Local machines? VMs? GHA-hosted runners? Self-hosted runners?

Comment: @azeem. There are all github hosted windows machines.  My .yml file has `runs_on: windows-latest` and github puts it where it wants it.  My error message is from the linker: "fatal error C1047: The object or library file 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\stuff_1.lib' was created by a different version of the compiler than other objects like 'build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\swig\stuff_wrap.obj'; rebuild all objects and libraries with the same compiler".  The file `stuff_1.lib` was created a few days prior using an identically hosted Windows machine and was saved in a github cache.

Comment: @azeem.  I'm determining the cl.exe and link.exe versions because they are literally in the filepath of the compile and link commands in the logs.  The logs themselves are several thousand lines, and I don't have permission to let others see them.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue and what I ended up doing is taking the version from the output of the tool. When you run `cl.exe` on the commandline, it will output the version number, add that content to a text file and use that textfile to compute the cache key:

In my case I needed the version of renovate bot. Calling `npm show renovate version` outputs the version to the output.

You could probably use the default output from calling `cl.exe`. In case of Microsoft Visual C++, or whatever tool you rely on. Just make sure the content you capture is constant and contains the version number.

See:

- https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-tasks/blob/be43d95afecd0376b7cb3f98f83ad248880ae019/.github/workflows/renovate.yml#L50-L55

```yaml
    - run: npm show renovate version >> renovate-lock.txt

    - uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: ${{ steps.npm-cache-dir.outputs.dir }}
        key: npm-cache-${{ hashFiles('renovate-lock.txt') }}
```

Comment: This may be exactly what I'm looking for. . . . Let me see.

Comment: `npm show renovate version` is showing me 35.124.0 on all three of Windows, Ubuntu, and MacOS.  So that's probably not the compiler version.  Is there a different command I should be trying?

Comment: Yes of course you need to use whatever executable that you rely on, this was my similar example. If it's MS VC++, you probably want to take the output from `cl.exe`.

Comment: Either `run: cl` or `run: cl.exe` as a step gives me the error message: "The term 'cl.exe' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program."  So I'm really back to my original question.  What command do I run to get the compiler version?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm actually compiling using `python setup.py build_ext` to compile some C files into a library.  Python somehow figures out where cl.exe is located.  I'm trying to understand how normal users find cl.exe.

Comment: There's a tool called `vswhere` that allows you to detect the location of tools installed by Visual Studio.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-VC